# What environment does JavaScript execute in?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In selenium-webdriver, JavaScript executed in the driven browser does not seem to have access to global variables of the active page. This is contrary to both the selenium docs and the WebDriver spec so possibly I've got something configured wrong.

The [google.com](http://www.google.com/) home page has a `gapi` global variable I can access manually in the console:

```
>> gapi
Object { load: pr.load(), loaded_0: null, _: Object, config: Object, iframes: Object, plusone: Object, platform: Object, widget: Object }
```

Trying to access this in script executed by selenium fails with a reference error:

```js
const driver = builder.build();
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
driver.executeScript(`alert(gapi);`);
// JavascriptError: ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
```

Values written to `window` are accessible in subsequent injected code but never make it to the main page. In selenium:

```js
driver.executeScript(`window.test='testvalue';`);
driver.executeScript(`alert(window.test);`);
// Alerts: testvalue
```

In the console after that alert is dismissed:

```
>> window.test
undefined
```

What is going on here? **What environment is the script injected by selenium executing in?**

Comment: `window.postMessage` from injected script delivers to the main page. In the listener `event.source===window` and `event.origin==='null'` (the string 'null'). Not sure what that indicates.

Comment: Scratch that, `event.origin==='null'` seems to be an artifact of accessing test pages locally. The HTML spec allows implementation specific origin definition for the file: URI scheme which ends up serializing to string 'null'.